# Forcing CURL(PHP) to access a different locale (pt-BR > en-US)

Tags: php, curl, locale

The website:
https://www.origin.com/pt-br/store/

My location: Brazil (pt-br)
My webhost location: USA (en-us)

I am using cURL to capture the store page, so i can collect the promotions and set on my website.

The problem is that everytime i access the store it "redirects" me to the en-us page, because my host is in the USA. But i need the pt-br page.

I've tried setting locale and time zone, but nothing works. If i execute from my pc, i get the pt-br page.
Any ideas of how i can trick the server to think my website is hosted in Brazil and not in the USA?

Code i'm using:

```
$url = 'https://www.origin.com/pt-br/store/';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: pt-BR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the desired language in your request headers? You may specify them in a priority list like this:

```
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

In this case the server is asked to deliver German as first option, if possible. As a fallback, the requesting instance (my browser) is also satisfied with US English (or just English) but with lower priorities (0.8 vs. 0.6 vs. 0.4). So you should try something like

```
Accept-Language:pt-BR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

It can be set by calling

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: pt-BR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"));
```

Comment: I've tried that too, forgot to mention, sorry.
Still getting the en-us page.

Comment: If you have tried something, please paste that code. Also, you said "because my host is in the USA", but this is just an assumption, right? It may also deliver in this locale because it's the default and your request does not contain the right stuff to change it. Maybe adding a browser-like user agent will do the trick. Have you compared the request your browser makes with the one you create in code? Does it work when you build the exact same request will all the params and headers set to the same values?

Comment: Code on the first post. I'm using firebug and tamper data to try discover what the server is doing, but no success.
And, no, i'm not guessing the location of host, it is in the USA.

Comment: I meant you're assuming that your host location is the reason for the problem, although it may be something else. I do not doubt that your host is in the US :-)